# IPMI client for Windows

Tags: windows, ipmi

Do you know a IPMI client for Windows supporting the protocol IPMI over Lan version 1.5?
I want extract sensors data(fan speed, temperature) from a HP Integrity Superdome with the IPMI over lan protocol enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so sure, but you might want to take a look at ipmiutil http://ipmiutil.sourceforge.net/